# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with following pdf's.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

The ilustration is below

[image]

Now the trouble that I have is to understand the limits on the integrals to
solve this problem. The answer is:

$\int_0^{1/2} \int_y^1 f_1(x) \: f_2(y)\: dx\:dy = \int_0^{1/2} \int_y^1 1 \cdot \: 8y\: dx\:dy$

$y$ is on the interval $0<y<1/2$, so this is why the first integral goes from $0$ to $1/2$. But why the second integral goes from $y$ to $1$? I have some problems to understand questions like this one.

Comment: What is being asked is for the range $X > Y$ which means that the area of $x<y$ is to be excluded, which corresponds to the region labeled $A$ in the picture. Since the limits in question are for $x$ then the region to be considered is $y \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't get, how do I know/see that $y<x<1$. I tried looking in the graph but I dont see what I suppose to be looking at to know the interval of $x$.

Comment: It starts with $Pr(X > Y)$. Meaning the proposed problem only considers the region $x > y$. From this point onward the graph gives meaning to the hatched region. Similarly if asked for $Pr(X < Y)$ then region $A$ is considered. The limits for this region are $\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{x}^{1/2}$, or $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $x \leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, but if I try to calculate the hatched region, how I do that? The book only gives the final answer but no resolution. I have problems to identify the right integrals or the intervals of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I can see why in the region $A$, $0<x<1/2$ but I fail to see why $x<y<1/2$. Or why in the hatched region $y<x<1$.